# like query doesn't work exact

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a little search application (I know I can use match against). But now is
the problem: If I'm search after a piece of a word, I'm finding the match, but if I do an exact match, it doesn't work...

My mysql code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Dames 
WHERE naam 
LIKE "%alessia%" LIMIT 0,28
```

$link->Stuk(1) is just a parameter and limit, is for the pagination.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us how the actual query string looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what to tell you.  If "exact match" means

```
SELECT * 
FROM Dames 
WHERE naam = "alessia" LIMIT 0,28
```

and nothing comes back, it's because there is no row with a `naam` value of `"alessia"` in the Dames table.